# Panda objects and plotting

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a panda data frame called 'cone'
I labeled the 11 columns in that frame
then I did `cone[["No experience"]].plot()` to show all the columns with that label
But then when I try to do

```
noExperience = pd.DataFrame(cone[["No experience"]])
cone[["No experience"]].rolling(2).mean.plot()
plt.show()
```

I get the error "'function' object has no attribute 'plot'"

How come the first bit of code worked to plot but this one didn't? How can I change my code to plot what I have with the rolling and mean function? I still would like to have the data with the columns of "No experience" stored in one variable as I tried to do as well.

Comment: I also tried: noExperience.rolling(2).mean.plot()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

noExperience = pd.DataFrame(cone[["No experience"]])
cone[["No experience"]].rolling(2).mean().plot()
plt.show()

mean is a function

Answer (score 1):

mean is a callable function so add'()' wherever you use it.
replace 'mean' in your code with 'mean()'